# Can someone help splitting a range into equal parts

Tags: divisibility

I have been stuck with a problem.

I been presented a range from 10k to 3000k.

I need to split this into ten sections. I go to do the math and things are not working out, can someone show me what i need to do an offer guidance because, i need to do this for a much more diffrent set of information.

Comment: Just divide the difference by $10$ and construct the intervals according to this new difference.

Comment: It'd be useful if you showed us the math you did and we could tell you where the error is.  I strongly suspect you are doing an indexing "off by one error"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error of some sort but I don't know which one.

Comment: Off by one errors often occur when one confuses counting the bodies of the sections [which you can't one-by-one one after another] with counting and placing the *endpoints* of a section which is that an endpoint starting a section must be exactly the same as the endpoint ending the previous section (so the *don't* go up one by one).   And because you have endpoints at *both* ends (but all but the first and last are shared) you will have one more end point than you have sections..  And the end points start at "0" and not at "1".  This can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: @fleablood i cant the work is done on a graphing calc.

Comment: Graphing calculator?  What parameters would you put in and what output would you want.  A graphic (or any other) calculator can only answer a question if you know how to ask it.  This is so far as I can tell a very difficult question to ask in terms of commands for a graphing calculator.  The problem of encoding what to ask would encapsulate thie entire issue of *solving* to begin with

Comment: @fleablood i apologize to be more clear i was dealing with kHz. i was in engineering mode floating point. Should i just omit the khz and just use the number.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a length that is $300 - 10=290$ km long.  If you split this into $10$ sections each section will be $290 \div 10 = 29$km long.

So the first one starts and $10$ and ends at $10+29=39$.  ANd the second one starts and $39$ and ends at $39 + 29 = 68$.  And so on...

Google Off by One error or Fencepost problem to be aware of intuitive but incorrect traps that people commonly fall for with they try to do these types problems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error